# Occurrences of reäl with diæresis?

Tags: diaeresis

It just occurred to me that writing *reäl* with a diæresis is useful for indicating the pronunciation /rɪəl/ rather than /ri(ə)l/ (or /riːl/?).  Are there any occurrences of this in literature?  (Is there a freely available corpus of English lit. that will settle this?)

Comment: What corpora did you try?

Comment: I just checked the [COCA corpus](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/) and [Google nGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=reäl&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=) real quick and got zip, zero hits for *reäl*. Of course, there are several [other free corpora](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/2578) we could investigate.

Comment: Adjective *real* as disyllable does occur in Joseph Addison's hymn "The Spacious Firmament on High" (3rd verse), demanded by the iambic tetrameter and so set by both [Haydn](http://www2.cpdl.org/wiki/images/d/d5/47_The_Spacious_Firmament_on_High.pdf) and Britten (who includes it in his *Noye's Fludde).* It bears no diaeresis, however.

Comment: @BrianDonovan, I thought this was fairly standard. The first pronunciation above is the first in the OED (although the (mac) SOED gives only the parenthesized one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be at least one text where a dieresis occurs over the "e" in "real", but I think that in practice, this is no longer an option in normal English writing.

From Google Books:

- > And they have indeed a great influënce, when preſented in his Spirit, as aforeſaid, to work in our hearts true and **reäl** repentance from all our ſins

  (*[The Way to the City of God Described, Etc](https://books.google.com/books?id=KPJmAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA143&dq=%22re%C3%A4l%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiQ_dnUpfrYAhWDv1MKHZGxDswQ6AEISzAG#v=onepage&q=%22re%C3%A4l%22&f=false),* 1678)